# SOQL doesn't work on pc (person account) fields

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, soql, person-accounts, aura-enabled

I have enabled Person Account in my organization.
I also created a field on `Contact` Object named `LinkedUser__c` (Lookup User), which can be different from `Owner` field.

Now, I have created a new LWC with an apex Controller (Aura Enabled Method)
I'm trying to query some `Account` based on the `Account.LinkedUser__pc` (PC means fields on contact which can be retrieved in Account when using Person Account)

This is my code,

```
public with sharing class LinkedLWCController {

@AuraEnabled
public static List<String> getLinkedUsers(String stores, String division){
    List<Store__c> storeList = [SELECT Name, Code__c FROM Store__c WHERE Name IN : stores];
    Set<String> codeStoreSet = new Set<String>();
    for(Store__c s : storeList){
        codeStoreSet.add(s.Code__c);
    }

    List<User> userList = [SELECT Id, Name, IsActive FROM User WHERE Code__c IN : codeStoreSet AND Division IN : division];
    Set<Id> userIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(User u : userList){
        userIds.add(u.Id);
    }
    System.debug('advisorsIds.size() - ' + advisorToAccountList.keySet().size()); //+50 users
    //CASE 1 
    List<Account> accountList = [SELECT Id, LinkedUser__pc FROM Account WHERE LinkedUser__pc != null AND LinkedUser__pc IN :userIds];
    System.debug('accountList.Size() - ' + accountList.Size()); // 0 (+250 with inspector)

    //CASE 2 
    List<Account> accountList = [SELECT Id, LinkedUser__pc FROM Account WHERE LinkedUser__pc != null];
    System.debug('accountList.Size() - ' + accountList.Size()); // +5000 because we don't have a WHERE IN clause


    //......

}
```

}

What's wrong, please? I tried many solutions, such as running this class using `without sharing`, I also checked FLS on this field, I'm a system admin, I have access to the apex class etc..
Also running this code in Anonymous Method get the same results.
Inspector obtain result when querying the exact same query

Do I miss some limitations about Aura Enabled method or Person Account fields?
Thanks for your help!